# How to call or is it possible to call WebMethod that is in the master page in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Lets say,
I have MasterPage which has a function in the .Master file.

```
  function ajaxer65612282013() {
            var data = "";
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'UserMaster.Master/ay_scl',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#msd").html((data.d));

                },
                error: function (result) {
                    console.log(result.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
```

now in the code behind file of the master page i have a function like below

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string ay_scl()
        {
            DataTable dt= BAL.getDataForSideBar();
            string retHtml = "";

            return retHtml;
        }
```

it is giving me error like below

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   The resource you are looking for has
>   been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

it seems to me it is not possible but i may be wrong.
so im here to clarify my doubt.
if it is possible how to do it? and whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Check your URL one more time :  url: 'UserMaster.Master/ay_scl',

Comment: AFAIK WebMethods have to exist in ASPX files, in your case i'd abstract out the method to a new ASPX page put the WebMethod in the code behind of that new page and then update your request to point to the new page.